# How to override function twentyten_comment

Tags: comments, theme-twenty-ten

I am running the *Twenty Ten* theme.  I want to override comment formatting for certain posts.  After researching how to do this, I copied the `twentyten_comment` function from the parent theme (`twentyten`) into the `functions.php` file for my child theme (`twentyten-child`).  To confirm that I am running the code from the child, I added code to display the word 'child' on the output.  I also modified the parent `twentyten` `functions.php` file to output the word 'parent' if that code is used.  (yes, I backed up the original file so I can restore it after I figure this out).

When I view a post (in this case a question) and its comment (an answer) I see the word 'parent' on the page rather than 'child' so I know that making changes to the child code is meaningless until it is the code that gets executed.

`twentyten_comment` is in an `if(function_exists())` statement in the parent theme so I should just be able to put a function named `twentyten_comment` in the child `functions.php` file to override it.

I have not been able to effectively override the parent function.  What am I missing?

I even tried changing the function name in the child `functions.php` file and using that name in the `wp_list_comments` callback in `comments.php`.  It fails to execute.

Comment: The last two sentences tell me that there is something going on in your theme(s) besides just swapping that function, which should work as you describe ([which matches notes in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php#L353)). I don't know how to guess at what else might have been altered.

Comment: I suspected that.  Don't know what though.  The _twentyten_ 'comments.php' contains 'wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyten_comment' ) );'  Overridding that function in the child 'functions.php' should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on another part of my website and found the issue.  For some reason, child functions.php was not being recognized by wordpress.

Mine was listed in the right admin toolbar as 'functions.php' not as

Theme-functions
'(functions.php)'

I copied the content, created a new 'functions.php' and pasted the contents into the new file; then uploaded it.

Now it works.